# Set email recipients on approval of a topic by moderator in KUNENA extension of joomla

Tags: php, email, joomla, email-processing, kunena

**This site is not developed by me and I have little knowledge in joomla**

Site type - forum
Platform - joomla 1.7.1
extension installed - Kunena 1.7.0

Process :- When a topic is added to a category by user, then this topic should be approved by the moderator of that category

and moderator can approve the topic

Now when a topic is approved by a moderator following mails are triggering

1. A mail to the Moderator(in Inbox) **OK**
2. Super Administrator(in Spam) **Should be in Inbox**
3. A Mail delivery failed mail to the user who uploaded the topic as below

[image]

My main problem is how to send mail successfully to user on approval of his topic

Answer (score 0):

Please go to Configuration->Security and then setup E-mail Moderators to Unapproved Posts

Then You should setup all categories with approve post by moderatores

Comment: I am not getting the option **setup E-mail Moderators to Unapproved Posts** you are talking about

Comment: I think that this option is not able in Your Kunena version. Please mail me on budrys.ms@gmail.com. I will try to help You.